# How do I access the controller node on a Openstack Autopilot install?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack

I currently have the Cannonical Openstack Autopilot installed and it works great.  I can create VM's/Volumes/Users etc... The problem is now I want to tear this deployment down but backup all the images (Instance images and Volume images) so I can re-install the entire thing on another openstack environment.  How do I go about doing that?

I've been reading about the glance image download but I don't know what server to SSH into in order to do that.  Here is the output of "juju status":

http://pastebin.com/qSZtwZe5

Just not sure what to do at this point or where to start off.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can juggle servers, I would recommend building a new cloud and then figuring out how to migrate the content.

A future version of the autopilot (thanks for the feedback :) will support building additional regions in the same cloud, so in future you could make the second region, which would I'm sure be able to migrate glance and cinder content between regions easily, then shut down the original region. Maybe, future FUTURE version :)